# Any replacement for Bugsense for ACRA

Tags: android, acra, bugsense

I am using Bugsense as backend for ACRA in Android. Bugsense is good and report presentation is very nice.

The problem I am facing is it only allow 500 free reports per month.

I am looking for a replacement which I can host on my server and have unlimited report.

Kevin Gaudin is working on [Acralyzer](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer) but looks like it is still work in progress.

Are their any other alternatives?

P.S

This question falls under **software tools commonly used by programmers** of FAQ.

Comment: Why not simply pay BugSense $20 (or whatever the price is) :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many more advanced analytics platform nowadays for mobile & web like  **flurry, mixpanel, *crittercism*, zubhium** . I found **crittercism** more useful for Mobile App Performance Monitoring and Crash Reporting!

Comment: +1, does it place nay limit on the number of crash report received and how much does it cost?

Comment: https://www.crittercism.com/signup  I've not yet tried! I will let you know once I implement that..

Comment: @codingcrow  no limit to the number of crashes !

Answer (score 2):

It's not a backend for ACRA, but you could use .[Google Analytics for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/)

They have support for Crahes and Exception as well. See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/exceptions)

//edit: sorry I skipped the part, that you wanted to host that on your own server. My bad

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TestFlight](https://testflightapp.com/) for crashreporting. Note it uses ACRA internally.

Answer (score 0):

This runs on App Engine, not your own server, but looks good: http://code.google.com/p/acra-reporter/.

There are a few linked in the (old) ACRA docs as well: http://code.google.com/p/acra/wiki/Contribs

Answer (score 0):

The creator of ACRA has launched an open source project named [Acralyzer](https://github.com/ACRA/acralyzer) as back-end of ACRA.

Comment: @danik I really have not used it, you will better off discussing it in a community at G+ https://plus.google.com/communities/106839572027159542064